# a better way than stat() to look for files in dir?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to find out whether certain files are in a certain folder. However, even though the files exist, the way I try to find them doesn't work in certain folders.

```
bool FileExists(string strFilename) {
  struct stat stFileInfo;
  bool blnReturn;
  int intStat;
  intStat = stat(strFilename.c_str(),&stFileInfo);
  if(intStat == 0) {
    // We were able to get the file attributes
    // so the file obviously exists.
    blnReturn = true;
    printf("Found file %s\n", strFilename.c_str());
  } else {
    blnReturn = false;
    printf("Didn't find file %s\n", strFilename.c_str());
  }

  return(blnReturn);
}
```

When I mount a dir in /mnt/ram .. it doesn't (and sometimes does ) find the files there, however when I use another directory which is on the disk, it always finds the files.

Is there any other way to find out whether files exist in the directory?

Thanks

Comment: what `errno` do you receive when the file is not found?

Comment: You should print the error message to obtain more detailed failure reason. Use `strerror` or `perror` functions. It is hard to guess which of many many possible failures has occurred.

Comment: The error message : cannot stat no such file or directory‎

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use opendir & readdir to check the contents of a directory?
Especially if you want to check for multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a `stat` call or any other directory/file listing depends on permissions of the calling process. `/mnt/ram` might well be hidden for the current user.

As mentioned in the comments, `opendir` and `readdir` are the idiomatic way to get a (recursive) directory listing. Obviously, `stat` is part of the idiom `:-)`.

Comment: If access rights on the parent directories prohibit access to the file in question `errno` shall be set to `EACCES`. To access the file itself no read, write or execute permission need to exist for the process calling `stat()`, as stated by `man 2 stat`: `No permissions are required on the file itself ...`. Anyway, the OS is free to choose to hide the file.

Comment: Any directory on the path to the file can deny access to see the file.